# How to use webpack in Javascript to hide api key

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend, api-key

I'm working on a simple javascript project (still learning) that requires an API.
Among the requirements there is the use of webpack to hide the api key, but as far as I know it is not possible to hide the key from a front end application without a back end (which i cannot use it yet) ... am I missing something ?? Do I have to add some Node.js code??

Comment: _"as far as I know it is not possible to hide the key from a front end application without a back end"_. Exactly

Comment: You could keep the `API_KEY` outside your code within a `.env` file, although it would still be visible on `inspect` within the browser. Is this what you desire?

Comment: so i was right :( so what's the use of having webpack in a vanilla javascript application?

Comment: thanks @Tolumide, but i still need a back end for the env files right?

Comment: No, you don't. I would be creating an answer here as to how to use `.env` with webpack.

Answer (score 2):

Within your webpack config, in the `plugins` part add this:

```
// webpack.config.js 
plugins: [
  ....
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    "process.env": {
      API_KEY: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_KEY),
    },
  }),
]
```

create a `.env` file, where you would add something like this:

```
// .env
API_KEY="thevalueOfTheAPIKey"
```

For the sake of security, your `.env` file must be added to the `.gitignore` file, you should also create a `.env.sample` file, that others can use, the whole essence of the `.env.sample` is to help others know how to recreate the `.env` file locally, so for something like what we have above you would have:

```
// .env.sample
API_KEY=""
```

Within your project, whereever you would be using the environment variable e.g.

```
// index.js
require("dotenv").config();

const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;
```

You can read more about `process.env` on the documentation here: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env